# pgsql2shp result as shapefile

Tags: python, postgis

In addition to https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/173746/pgsql2shp-command-join-error?noredirect=1#comment260108_173746, the next command line works fine in order to join a table to a shapefile but the result is a dbf table and not a shapefile as I want. I see that exists a -g geom parameter but I try and it doesn't work. How do I get the geometry?

```
pgsql2shp -f "C:\....\teste2.shp" -h localhost -p 5432 -u postgres -P postgres database_name "SELECT table2.example, table2.example2 FROM table1 LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 ON table1.dicofre = table2.reside"
```

Comment: I suggest you run the query inside psql or pgAdmin to see what it returns first. If the query is correct and data is returned,  shp, dbf and shx (and optinally a prj) files will be produced.

Comment: In pgAdmin I can only test the SELECT part right? But If I put that line in pgAdmin, it doesn't generate a shapefile. Can you explain to me how do I use pgsql2shp into pgAdmin?

Comment: You don't. It was just to clarify that the query returns something